# Upload a File with MVC HttpPostedFileBase == null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

My Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    return this.EditDefault(id);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Models.Company model)
{
    return this.EditDefault(id, model);
}
```

My Model

```
pulbic class Company
{
    ... Many other Propeties
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ... Many other Properties
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new
    {
        type = "file", style = "display:none" 
    })
    ... Submit
}
```

So my problem now is when I submit the page the infos in the model are right, but the File Property is still null.

I found some solutions where people added HttpPostedFileBase as parmeter in the controller (tried it doesn't work too), but I would like to avoid that anyway because the model and the controller are generated with T4. So has someone an idea why the File Property is always null?

Would be really happy about some help :)

**Update:** Found the solution thx to Matt Tabor.

For me the solution looks like this because I use a shared Edit page.
The javascript part is to hide the actual file upload element and use a span instead, because the file upload isn't style able.

```
//Shared Part
@{
    RouteData routeData = this.ViewContext.RouteData;
    string currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", currentController, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    //Special Part
    ... Many other Properties
    //File upload which is hidden
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new
    {
        type = "file", style = "display:none" 
    })
    //Span which forwards the clicks to the file upload
    <span id="fake-file-name">Kein Bild</span>
    ... Submit
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //forward the click from the span to the file upload
        $("#fake-file-name").click(function () {
            $("#File").click();
        });
        //display the chosen file name to the user with the styled span
        $("#File").bind('change', function () {
            //we don't want the C:\fakepath to show
            var displayFileName = this.value.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");
            $("#fake-file-name").text(displayFileName);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Check This: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/HttpPostedFileBase-getting-file-extension-in-Asp-Net-MVC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to specify your form method as post

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "CONTROLLER", null,FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =   "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new
> {
>     type = "file", style = "display:none" 
> })
> ```

Instead have a Input type file as shown below -

```
<input type="file" name="File" id="File"/>
```

PS: Name should match to Model property name.

**UPDATE**
Remove **display:none** from your code and it should work fine.

Comment: thx but tried it and doesn't work.
Btw this:
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new
    {
        type = "file", style = "display:none" 
    })
generates this
<input id="File" name="File" style="display:none" type="file" value="">
So does pretty much the same

Comment: What happens when you remove display:none style and give a try?